# After upgrading MS office 2003 to MS office 2007 export with excel with png image not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

We are using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel to insert the image in the excel, below is the code which fails. It is working in MS Office 2003 version, after upgrading to MS Office 2007 its not working.

```
excelHelper.InsertImage(ganttFilePath, 395, 70, (float)ganttWidth, (float)ganttHeight)
```

Comment: No error message;no response from server ;excel object not dispose

Comment: if the image size is <20kb i am able to insert image

Comment: Mhm, check in the offical documentation if there is a limitation on the size of the file/timeout on the upload of the file. Or just check both documentations if there is anything different now.

Comment: I am able to download the excel with image but excel.exe is not getting killed and hangs in the task manager

Comment: So what have you tried to end excel ? usually Process.Kill("Excel.exe") should do it ;) Try something, post it as new question if it wont work, and then you get help.

Comment: We have solved this issue by dcomcnfg ->microsoft excel->property->identy->selecting This user and add service account and login with added service account.

Answer (score 1):

We have solved this issue by dcomcnfg ->microsoft excel->property->identy->selecting This user and add service account and login with added service account.